# Nginx as reverse proxy, can't get full url in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am unable to get the complete URL using `var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;`

suppose I am calling this on route /getUrl

I should get http://<server_ip>/app/users/happy/getUrl

instead I only get http://<server_ip>/getUrl

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy.

```
location /app/users/happy/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:4216/;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
      proxy_redirect ~/(.*)$ /app/users/happy/$1;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
```

I also tried adding
`app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');`

Answer (score 1):

The proxy converts a request

```
GET http://<proxy_ip>/app/users/happy/getUrl HTTP/1.1
Host: <proxy_ip>
```

into

```
GET http://<server_ip>/getUrl HTTP/1.1
Host: <server_ip>
X-Forwarded-Host: <server_ip>
X-<other headers mentioned in the nginx directive>
```

Therefore the prefix `/app/users/happy` never reaches your server. You could add it in yet another header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Path-Prefix /app/users/happy
```

and obtain it as `req.get("X-Path-Prefix")`, but what do you need it for?